# adding new font android application

Tags: android, fonts, styles

I'm trying to add a custom font to my android application. 
I've added the font under 'assets' folder.
I've come across code that allows you to add it programmatically to a specific view. 
I want to add the new font to my entire application and call it through my style.xml file

Answer (score 0):

First add the font style file to the assets folder than create class file for accessing that font file.

**FontStyle.java**

```
public class FontStyle {
    public static Typeface OswaldRegular(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Oswald-Regular.ttf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Just replace your font file name into the above code and for that font style you can code into your MainActivity.java for

```
txt.setTypeface(FontStyle.OswaldRegular(CustomCameraActivity.this));
```

If anything you need to know, feel free to contact me.